# Duplicating or using Save As for a Code Workbook

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-workbooks

What's the best way to duplicate a workbook? I can't see any Save As button. Is the only option copying all the nodes and pasting into another workbook?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the only way to do this is to copy-paste.